# FATAL ERROR com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error and I can't find the reason. I try to retrieve lat and long from Firebase. Here its my code from Java class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    private DatabaseReference mUsers;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // initializing our firebase firestore.
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get
        // notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
        mUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations");
        mUsers.push().setValue(marker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        mUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        MapAdapter mapAdapter = dataSnapshot.getValue(MapAdapter.class);
                        LatLng location = new LatLng(mapAdapter.latitude, mapAdapter.longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my code from the adapter:

```
public class MapAdapter {
     public Long latitude,longitude ;

    public MapAdapter() {

    }

    public Long getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Long latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Long getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Long longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBO6e.png)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wss503, PID: 18029
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertLong(CustomClassMapper.java:385)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(CustomClassMapper.java:296)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:215)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.example.wss503.MapsActivity$1.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:62)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Post the full error in the question. Error at <line>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> FATAL ERROR com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Because you are trying to read the latitude and longitude as `long` values, while in the database are stored as strings, which is not correct. See the double quotes?

[image]

To solve this, you either change the type of the fields in the database to be numbers and you leave the code as it is, or you change the `MapAdapter` class like this:

```
public class MapAdapter {
    public String latitude, longitude;

    public MapAdapter() {}

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

And you also change the code like this:

```
MapAdapter mapAdapter = dataSnapshot.getValue(MapAdapter.class);
long latitude = Long.parseLong(mapAdapter.latitude);
long longitude = Long.parseLong(mapAdapter.longitude);
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```